# BeautifulSoup steam market web scraping errors

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, anaconda

I'm attempting to write a program using, python and BeautifulSoup4, that looks at the steam market front page for a certain game (in this case Rust) and looks at each of the items and takes their name and price. So far I have managed to get this working for the first page (as each page only shows 10 items however when I change the web address for the second page I get the exact same output of the first page.

The URL i'm using for the first page is:https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=252490#p1_popular_desc

The second page is:https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=252490#p2_popular_desc

The code is:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

for web_page in range(1,3):
    print('webpage number is: '+ str(web_page))
    if web_page == 1:
        url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=252490#p1_popular_desc"
        print(url)
        sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')


    if web_page == 2:
        urlADD = '#p2_popular_desc'
        url ="https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=252490#p2_popular_desc"
        print(url)

        sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')



    for div in soup.find_all('a',class_='market_listing_row_link'):
        span = div.find('span',class_='normal_price')
        span2 = div.find('span',class_='market_listing_item_name')
        print(span2.text)
        print(span.text)
```

I'm not sure whats wrong here help would be welcome.

Comment: api: https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=0&count=100&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=popular&sort_dir=desc&appid=252490

Comment: Someone tried to solve your issues and you on the other hand didn't care to respond @Matthew Cudby. However, taken that out.

Comment: Sorry in between school and extra curricular I’ve been trying out the different ways you guys have given me. Sorry for being rude I’ll be more prompt in replying next time I appreciate the help I get from this community so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: 
you need to install selenium and geckodriver for firefox though
you will need this [pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) (Happy scripting :>)

```
#Mossein~King(1m here to help)
import time
import selenium
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

#for.testing.purposes.only
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = ''
driver.get(url)

#pages you like to interact with
pages = 2
for x in xrange(pages):
    pagesource = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pagesource)
    #do your stuff

    #go to next page
    #example if next button is <a class='MosseinKing Is Awesome'>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='MosseinKing Is Awesome']").click()
    #wait for 2 seconds for page to load
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thanks , never heard of it before i'll have a look at it.

Comment: awesome. if you encounter any challenge i'll walk you through it

Comment: I'm getting an error of:  'list' object has no attribute 'click' on the line of code :                                                                  
  driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchResults_btn_next"]').click()

Comment: Dw I found the error: you dont need the 's' in find_elements_by_xpath()

Comment: @CaveMan, using `time.sleep()` is against all best practices. It'll make the program slower or in some cases not reliable if the page doesn't load in 2 seconds. Have a look at @Shahin 's solution above. (You can see the use of [`explicit wait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits))

Comment: Hi. following up. yeah go for element not elements. @MatthewCudby. Yea explicit wait is better. -Thanks